# Why am I obtaining this "detached entity passed to persist" when I first retrieve the object that has to be used in a @ManyToMany relationship?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am working on a Spring Boot project using Spring Data JPA. I am pretty new in Hibernate mapping and I have the following doubts.

**NOTE:** I first implemented my DB tables, then I am mapping these tables into Java entity classes.

I have this User class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "portal_user")
@Getter
@Setter
public class User implements Serializable {
     
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5062673109048808267L;
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(name = "middle_name")
    private String middleName;
    
    @Column(name = "surname")
    private String surname;
    
    @Column(name = "sex")
    private char sex;
    
    @Column(name = "birthdate")
    private Date birthdate;
    
    @Column(name = "tex_code")
    private String taxCode;
    
    @Column(name = "e_mail")
    private String eMail;
    
    @Column(name = "contact_number")
    private String contactNumber;
    
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private Date createdAt;
    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<Address> addressesList = new HashSet<>();
    
    //@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    //@JsonManagedReference
    //private Set<User_UserType> userToUserTypeAssociation = new HashSet<>();
    
    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(
        name = "portal_user_user_type", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "portal_user_id_fk") }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_type_id_fk") }
    )
    //Set<UserType> userTypes;
    List<UserType> userTypes;


    public User(String firstName, String middleName, String surname, char sex, Date birthdate, String taxCode,
            String eMail, String contactNumber, Date createdAt) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.middleName = middleName;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.sex = sex;
        this.birthdate = birthdate;
        this.taxCode = taxCode;
        this.eMail = eMail;
        this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }
        

}
```

as you can see it contains this **@ManyToMany relationshipt based on the **portal_user_user_type** association table:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
@JoinTable(
    name = "portal_user_user_type", 
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "portal_user_id_fk") }, 
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_type_id_fk") }
)
//Set<UserType> userTypes;
List<UserType> userTypes;
```

This is my **UserType** entity classes mapping the **user_type** DB table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_type")
@Getter
@Setter
public class UserType implements Serializable {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6904959949570501298L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name = "type_name")
    private String typeName;
    
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userType")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<User_UserType> userToUserTypeAssociation = new HashSet<>();
    

    public UserType() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    
    public UserType(String typeName, String description) {
        super();
        this.typeName = typeName;
        this.description = description;
    }

}
```

Then I created this JUnit test method:

```
@SpringBootTest()
@ContextConfiguration(classes = GetUserWsApplication.class)
@TestMethodOrder(OrderAnnotation.class)
public class UserRepositoryTest {
    
    @Autowired
    private UsersRepository userRepository;
    
    @Autowired 
    UserTypeRepository userTypeRepository;
    
    @Test
    @Order(1)
    public void testInsertUser() {
        
        User user = new User("Luca", null, "Verdi", 'M', new Date(), "XXX", "xxx@gmail.com", "329123456", new Date());
        
        Set<Address> addressesList = new HashSet<>();
        addressesList.add(new Address("Italy", "RM", "00100", "Via XXX 123", "near YYY", user));
        
        user.setAddressesList(addressesList);
        
        //List<UserType> userTypesList = userTypeRepository.findAll();
        List<UserType> userTypesList = new ArrayList<UserType>();

        //Set<UserType> userTypesList = new HashSet<>();
        UserType userType1 = new UserType("ADMIN", "Admin user type !!!");
        UserType userType2 = new UserType("USER", "Just a simple user...");
        
        userTypesList.add(userType1);
        userTypesList.add(userType2);
        
        //user.setUserToUserTypeAssociation(user_UserType_List);
        user.setUserTypes(userTypesList);
        
        userRepository.save(user);
        assertTrue(true);
        
    }
    
}
```

Running this test method it works as I expected. Basically it inserted a new record into the **portal_user** table (mapped by my **User** entity class), then it inserted a record into the **user_type** table (mapped by the **UserType** entity class) and also it inserted the relationship into my **Many To many** association table named **portal_user_user_type**).

Ok, now I have the following situation. The **user_type** table mapped by the **UserType** class is a typological table. It contains the predefined information related the possible user types (such as: "ADMIN", "MODERATOR", "USER", etcetc).

So this table must be pre populated and I have not to insert new records into this table but I have to use the existing record to populate my **portal_user_user_type** association table when a new user is created.

So my idea was the following one:

1. I first retrieve the list of possible UserType instances via a JPA repository.
2. Differently from the previous code, instead to create these **UserType** instances I set this list into my user object.

I don't know if this is the correct strategy. Anyway I have changed the previous code of my unit test method in this way and I am obtaining some problems:

```
@SpringBootTest()
@ContextConfiguration(classes = GetUserWsApplication.class)
@TestMethodOrder(OrderAnnotation.class)
public class UserRepositoryTest {
    
    @Autowired
    private UsersRepository userRepository;
    
    @Autowired 
    UserTypeRepository userTypeRepository;
    
    
    @Test
    @Order(1)
    public void testInsertUser() {
        
        User user = new User("Luca", null, "Verdi", 'M', new Date(), "XXX", "xxx@gmail.com", "329123456", new Date());
        
        Set<Address> addressesList = new HashSet<>();
        addressesList.add(new Address("Italy", "RM", "00100", "Via XXX 123", "near YYY", user));
        
        user.setAddressesList(addressesList);
        
        List<UserType> userTypesList = userTypeRepository.findAll();
        
        user.setUserTypes(userTypesList);
        
        userRepository.save(user);
        assertTrue(true);
        
    }
    
}
```

As you can see I am first retrieving the user types list by this JPA repository, then I am setting this list (instead the one that I manually created in the previous version of the test method):

```
List<UserType> userTypesList = userTypeRepository.findAll();
user.setUserTypes(userTypesList);
```

The  retrieved user type is something like this (this list was retrieved by my **userTypeRepository.findAll()** call):

[image]

So I set it using the **setUserTypes()** method (as I have done before with the UserType object that was manually created).

The problem is that when this line is executed:

```
userRepository.save(user);
```

I obtain the following exception:

```
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        portal_user
        (birthdate, contact_number, created_at, e_mail, first_name, middle_name, sex, surname, tex_code) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        address
        (country, notes, province, street, fk_user_id, zip_code) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: com.easydefi.users.entity.UserType; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.easydefi.users.entity.UserType
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:297)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy105.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.easydefi.users.tests.RepositoryTests.UserRepositoryTest.testInsertUser(UserRepositoryTest.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.easydefi.users.entity.UserType
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:744)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:712)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$7.cascade(CascadingActions.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:499)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:423)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:532)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:463)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:426)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:459)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:720)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:706)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy102.persist(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:597)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:529)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:599)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:163)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    ... 75 more
```

The problems seems to be this **detached entity passed to persist** but what it means?

How can I try to fix this issue? and what could be a good approach to first retrieve the list of the possible **UserTypes** and then to insert a new User with the relation with these retrieved user types avoiding to inser them again in the DB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a problem with Cascade type you are using. Here you are setting the cascade type to `CascadeType.ALL`

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
@JoinTable(
    name = "portal_user_user_type", 
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "portal_user_id_fk") }, 
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_type_id_fk") }
)
//Set<UserType> userTypes;
List<UserType> userTypes;
```

Why this is a bad idea? When you do a `CascadeType.ALL` on the child entity, it will cause every DB operation to be propagated to the entity UserType. Since Transaction is PERSISTED, it tries to PERSIST UserType as well and that doesn't work since UserType already is in the db. To fix this use `CascadeType.MERGE` instead as with it the UserType will be automatically merged instead. So change this line:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE})
```

Also as a side note, I assume UserType entities are unique? So consider using set instead of list for storing them, as you do not want duplicates.